# problem with installation of agricolae package (installation of package had non-zero exit status) in R

Tags: r

Good day. I have a problem with installation of agricolae package (R version is 3.2.3. When I enter `install.packages("agricolae")` I have following:

> ```
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> Warning in install.packages :
>   dependency ‘spdep’ is not available
> also installing the dependencies ‘httpuv’, ‘later’, ‘promises’, ‘shiny’, ‘miniUI’, ‘questionr’, ‘klaR’
>
>
>   There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
>           binary  source needs_compilation
> httpuv     1.3.3   1.4.5              TRUE
> shiny      1.0.2   1.1.0             FALSE
> miniUI     0.1.1 0.1.1.1             FALSE
> questionr  0.6.0   0.6.3             FALSE
> klaR      0.6-12  0.6-14             FALSE
> agricolae  1.2-4   1.2-8             FALSE
>
> Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
> y/n: y
> Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
>   ‘later’ ‘promises’
> Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
> y/n: y
> installing the source packages ‘httpuv’, ‘later’, ‘promises’, ‘shiny’, ‘miniUI’, ‘questionr’, ‘klaR’, ‘agricolae’
> ```

After downloading of all packages Rstudio shows me this:

> ```
> * installing *source* package 'later' ...
> ** package 'later' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
>    **********************************************
>    WARNING: this package has a configure script
>          It probably needs manual configuration
>    **********************************************
> ```
>
> ** libs
>
> *** arch - i386
>
> g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG
>   -DTHREADS_H_SUPPORT=-1   -I"C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/(User
>   name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH/include"
>   -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
>
> g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG
>   -DTHREADS_H_SUPPORT=-1   -I"C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/(User
>   name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH/include"
>   -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c callback_registry.cpp -o callback_registry.o
>
> gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG
>   -DTHREADS_H_SUPPORT=-1   -I"C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/(User
>   name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH/include"
>   -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c init.c -o init.o
>
> g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG
>   -DTHREADS_H_SUPPORT=-1   -I"C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/(User
>   name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH/include"
>   -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c later.cpp -o later.o
>
> g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG
>   -DTHREADS_H_SUPPORT=-1   -I"C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/(User
>   name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH/include"
>   -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c later_native.cpp -o later_native.o
>
> g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG
>   -DTHREADS_H_SUPPORT=-1   -I"C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/(User
>   name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH/include"
>   -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c later_posix.cpp -o later_posix.o
>
> g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG
>   -DTHREADS_H_SUPPORT=-1   -I"C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/(User
>   name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH/include"
>   -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c later_win32.cpp -o later_win32.o
>
> g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG
>   -DTHREADS_H_SUPPORT=-1   -I"C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/(User
>   name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH/include"
>   -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c timer_posix.cpp -o timer_posix.o
>
> g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG
>   -DTHREADS_H_SUPPORT=-1   -I"C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/(User
>   name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH/include"
>   -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c timestamp_unix.cpp -o timestamp_unix.o
>
> g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG
>   -DTHREADS_H_SUPPORT=-1   -I"C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/(User
>   name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH/include"
>   -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c timestamp_win32.cpp -o timestamp_win32.o
>
> gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG
>   -DTHREADS_H_SUPPORT=-1   -I"C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/(User
>   name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/BH/include"
>   -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c tinycthread/tinycthread.c -o tinycthread/tinycthread.o
>
> g++ -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o later.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o
>   callback_registry.o init.o later.o later_native.o later_posix.o
>   later_win32.o timer_posix.o timestamp_unix.o timestamp_win32.o
>   ./tinycthread/tinycthread.o
>   -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/i386 -lR
>
> ./tinycthread/tinycthread.o:tinycthread.c:(.text+0x5a9): undefined
>   reference to '_imp___ftime_s'
>
> ./tinycthread/tinycthread.o:tinycthread.c:(.text+0x9b0): undefined
>   reference to '_imp___ftime_s'
>
> ./tinycthread/tinycthread.o:tinycthread.c:(.text+0xbc9): undefined
>   reference to '_imp___ftime_s'
>
> ./tinycthread/tinycthread.o:tinycthread.c:(.text+0xec9): undefined
>   reference to '_imp___ftime_s'
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> no DLL was created
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package 'later'
>
> removing 'C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/later'
>
> Warning in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users(User
>   name)\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users(User
>   name)\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi439vE/downloaded_packages/later_0.7.5.tar.gz'
>   had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘later’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency 'later' is not available for
>   package 'promises'
>   removing 'C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/promises'
>
> Warning in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users(User
>   name)\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users(User
>   name)\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi439vE/downloaded_packages/promises_1.0.1.tar.gz'
>   had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘promises’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies 'promises', 'later' are not
>   available for package 'httpuv'
>   removing 'C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/httpuv'
>
> Warning in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users(User
>   name)\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users(User
>   name)\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi439vE/downloaded_packages/httpuv_1.4.5.tar.gz'
>   had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘httpuv’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies 'httpuv', 'later', 'promises'
>   are not available for package 'shiny'
>   removing 'C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/shiny'
>
> Warning in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users(User
>   name)\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users(User
>   name)\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi439vE/downloaded_packages/shiny_1.1.0.tar.gz'
>   had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘shiny’ had
>   non-zero exit status
>
> ERROR: dependency 'shiny' is not available for package 'miniUI'
>   removing 'C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/miniUI'
>
> Warning in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users(User
>   name)\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users(User
>   name)\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi439vE/downloaded_packages/miniUI_0.1.1.1.tar.gz'
>   had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘miniUI’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies 'shiny', 'miniUI' are not
>   available for package 'questionr'
>
> removing 'C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/questionr'
>   Warning in install.packages :
>
> running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l
>   "C:\Users(User name)\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users(User
>   name)\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi439vE/downloaded_packages/questionr_0.6.3.tar.gz'
>   had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘questionr’
>   had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency 'questionr' is not
>   available for package 'klaR'
>
> removing 'C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/klaR'
>
> Warning in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users(User
>   name)\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users(User
>   name)\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi439vE/downloaded_packages/klaR_0.6-14.tar.gz'
>   had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘klaR’ had
>   non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies 'klaR', 'spdep' are not
>   available for package 'agricolae'
>
> removing 'C:/Users/(User name)/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/agricolae'
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>
> running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l
>   "C:\Users(User name)\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users(User
>   name)\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi439vE/downloaded_packages/agricolae_1.2-8.tar.gz'
>   had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>
> installation of package ‘agricolae’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in     ‘C:\Users(User
>   name)\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpi439vE\downloaded_packages’

Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with the R version. Try to update your R installation to >= 3.5 and you should be fine.